# How to find duplicates in an ArrayList which is in the form of JSON object?

Tags: java

I am having an option in my website for the user i.e: "Settings" in that I given 3 options(TextBoxes) to enter details: 1.E-mail, 2.SMS, 3.MMS.. in this user can enter another mail id: its an optional thing but, if he enter the both or same which is neccesary e-mail and optional or same then, I have to tell that "given e-mail" alredy exist.

I am sending this data as ArrayList that to coverted as JSON object.

What is the best way to find the duplicate and notify that to user

Help me in this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Either parse it into Java collections with a JSON framework of your choice, then check for duplicates or use JavaScript to directly work on the JSON.

If you have the ArrayList anyway, why don't iterate over that?

Answer (score 0):

Please do the following

```
 HashSet hashSet = new HashSet(arrayList1);  
 ArrayList arrayList2 = new ArrayList(hashSet) ;
 if(arrayList2.size()<arrayList1.size()){
 //duplicates exits
 }
```

Comment: a) oh please! this is non-generic Java 1.4 code. b) arrayList2 is unnecessary, you can compare hashSet.size() with arrayList1.size()

Answer (score 0):

You can do what Ammu posted, but this will not identify the duplicate entry. If you have the ArrayList as a Java object (if not, convert it into one), convert the ArrayList into a HashSet, compare the size to identify if there are duplicate entries. If so, you need to sort the ArrayList in order to find the duplicate entry.

```
Collections.sort(arrayList);
    for(int i = 1; i < arrayList.size() - 1; i++){
        if (arrayList.get(i).equals(arrayList.get(i - 1))){
            // found duplicate 
            System.out.println("Duplicate!");
        }

    }
```

this works only if the entries of the ArrayList implement the sortable interface. But since your ArrayList is filled with strings this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you described

> "... in this user can enter another
>   mail id: its an optional thing but, if
>   he enter the both or same which is
>   neccesary e-mail and optional or same
>   then, I have to tell that "given
>   e-mail" alredy exist."

I would alert the user using Javascript and avoid the HTTP Request/Response round-trip to the server:

```
...
// before submitting the form
if (document.getElementById('requiredEmail').value == document.getElementById('optionalEmail').value) {
    alert("The optional email must be different than the required email");
}
...
```

As suggested before by other user, you can just create a Set based on the ArrayList if you are validating the input in the backend...

```
    String[] parsedInput = new String[] { "SMS-Value", "MMS-Value", "email@domain.com", "email@domain.com" }
    List<String> receivedList = Arrays.asList(parsedInput);
    Set<String> validatedList = new HashSet<String>(receivedList);

    if (validatedList.size() < receivedList.size()) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("The email addresses provided are incorrect.");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to find the duplicates then you can iterate over the list and find.
   like:

   ```
   Map<Object, Integer> map = new HashMap<Object, Integer>();
   for(Object obj : list)
   {
       if(map.containsKey(obj))
          {
          map.put(obj, map.get(obj)+1);
      }
      else
      {
         map.put(obj, 1);
      }
   }
   ```

   Objects in the map having value more than 1 are duplicate.
2. If you just want to get rid of duplicates (rather than knowing which are actually duplicates)
   Ex:

   ```
    Set set = new HashSet(list);
   ```

set can not have duplicate elements, so it will remove all duplicates.